# How to create a new column which gives the number of days in that particular month in python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains 'year' and 'month' as separate columns. So let's say it looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhSqG.png)

How can I create another column with the number of days in that particular month?

I have tried using a for and if loop which looks like:

```
def n_days(Month):
  for index, M in enumerate(Month):
    if Month[index] == 1:
      Month[index] = 31
    if Month[index] == 3:
      Month[index] = 31
    if Month[index] == 5:
      Month[index] = 31
    if Month[index] == 7:
      Month[index] = 31
    if Month[index] == 8:
      Month[index] = 31
    if Month[index] == 10:
      Month[index] = 31
    if Month[index] == 12:
      Month[index] = 31
    if Month[index] == 4:
      Month[index] = 30
    if Month[index] == 6:
      Month[index] = 30
    if Month[index] == 9:
      Month[index] = 30
    if Month[index] == 11:
      Month[index] = 30
    if Month[index] == 2:
      Month[index] = 28
  return Month
```

It is working perfect for non-leap years and I am not dealing with leap years. But I just want to know whether there is an easier and shorter way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use monthrange() from calender module inside apply:

```py
from calendar import monthrange

df["days"] = df.apply(lambda row: monthrange(row["year"], row["month"])[1], axis=1)
```

And here is an example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                     


In [2]:                                                                         

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2018,2019], "month": [1,2]})                

In [3]: df                                                                      
Out[3]: 
   year  month
0  2018      1
1  2019      2

In [4]: from calendar import monthrange                                         

In [5]: df["days"] = df.apply(lambda row: monthrange(row["year"], row["month"])[
   ...: 1], axis=1)                                                             

In [6]: df                                                                      
Out[6]: 
   year  month  days
0  2018      1    31
1  2019      2    28

In [7]:
```

Another example to see handling leap years:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2017,2018,2019,2020,2021], "month": [2,2,2,2
   ...: ,2]})                                                                   

In [8]: df                                                                      
Out[8]: 
   year  month
0  2017      2
1  2018      2
2  2019      2
3  2020      2
4  2021      2

In [9]: df["days"] = df.apply(lambda row: monthrange(row["year"], row["month"])[
   ...: 1], axis=1)                                                             

In [10]: df                                                                     
Out[10]: 
   year  month  days
0  2017      2    28
1  2018      2    28
2  2019      2    28
3  2020      2    29
4  2021      2    28

In [11]:
```

Comment: OMG thank you I think it is working very well!!! Actually I was considering using monthrange but I didn't know how to make it work on a dataframe!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `calendar` module:

```
import calendar
def n_days(Month):
    return calendar.mdays
```

Comment: but it only gave me a list of number of days from Jan to Dec I think. In my loop n_days(Month) the 'Month' represents a list of months from the dataframe. So actually Month = list(df['month'])

Comment: how can I have a function that gives a column of  number of days depending on the corresponding month value in the dataframe

Comment: That is a good question. My code does exactly what your code does, ie. just return an array of the number of days in the corresponding month. If you pass in the month number (1-based) then `return calendar.mdays[month_number - 1]` would get you there...

Comment: Thanks I will go and try it out again

Answer (score 0):

try [pandas.Series.dt.daysinmonth](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.daysinmonth.html#pandas-series-dt-daysinmonth)

Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2019,2019,2019,2019],'month':[1,2,6,12]})
>>> df
   month  year
0      1  2019
1      2  2019
2      6  2019
3     12  2019

# create new column
df['daysinmonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'].astype(str)  + \
                                   df['month'].astype(str), format='%Y%m').dt.daysinmonth

>>> df
   month  year  daysinmonth
0      1  2019           31
1      2  2019           28
2      6  2019           30
3     12  2019           31
```